# How to access elemens in Row RDD in SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My row RDD looks like this:

```
Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([1,[example1,WrappedArray([**Standford,Organisation,NNP], [is,O,VP], [good,LOCATION,ADP**])]])
```

I have got this from converting dataframe to rdd, dataframe schema was :

```
root
 |-- article_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- sentence: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sentence: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- attributes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- tokens: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ner: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pos: string (nullable = true)
```

Now how do access elements in row rdd, in dataframe I can use df.select("sentence"). I am looking forward to access elements like stanford/other nested elements.

Comment: The elements in a `RDD[Row]` are the `Row`s. You access them as you will in case of any other RDD like `RDD[String]` or `RDD[Int]`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh- can you show me how to access pos for an example

Comment: If the given answer solved your issue, please accept it otherwise comment why it did work for you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @SarveshKumarSingh wrote in a comment you can access a the rows in a  `RDD[Row]` like you would access any other element in an RDD. Accessing the elements in the row can be done in a couple of ways. Either simply call `get` like this:

```
rowRDD.map(row => row.get(2).asInstanceOf[MyType])
```

or if it is a build in type, you can avoid the type cast:

```
rowRDD.map(row => row.getList(4))
```

or you might want to simply use pattern matching, like:

```
rowRDD.map{case Row(field1: Long, field2: MyType) => field2}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes it helps, can you also tell me if I can directly convert dataframe objects to PUT or I need to convert it to RDD first. I want to save this dataframe in Hbase..